# RegExp word should not start with particular character for other word only find double quote word

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to write regExp for word should not start with and only select double quotes value output

e.g

1. notstart testing "testing" => no match
2. start testing "testing" => "testing"
3. anything testing testing => no match

   I have written following regExp but it does not work with second scenario

   `^(?!notstart).*(?:\s+)".*"$`

Comment: You should be `\b` to match a word boundary.

Comment: @anubhava its need give me output only "testing" its giving me whole word for second option

Comment: Perhaps use a capturing group `^(?!notstart).*("[^"]+")$` https://regex101.com/r/E2iTDC/1

Comment: Your example just shows true/false. Are you actually trying to capture or not? If so, what output do you want for each example?

Comment: Modern browsers will support: `/(?<!^notstart.*)"[^"]*"$/gm`

Comment: @anubhava thank you for the solution its working only one concern while checking its getting only failed if I have multiple double quote example for second scenario like 
start "testing" "testing" => "testing" "testing"

Comment: Try: `/(?<!^notstart.*?)"[^"]*"/gm`

Comment: @anubhava working can you please add it in answer so i can mark it as answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modern Javascript browsers support dynamic length lookbehind assertions. Hence you may consider this regex:

```
/(?<!^notstart.*?)"[^"]*"/gmi
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/r2gjT3/1)

- `(?<!^notstart.*?)`: Negative lookbehind assertion to fail the match if a match has `notstart` at line start.
- `"[^"]*"`: Match a quoted word. (This doesn't take care of escaped or unbalanced quotes).

Comment: Seems like using two regexes would be much better for performance: one to check the beginning of the string (actually just `startsWith` is sufficient), then a second regex to extract the quoted strings. As written, this looks like the complexity will explode because each match needs to backtrack to the beginning of the string to check the front.

Comment: Yes, in general performance wise any non-regex approach would be faster.

Comment: Still a nice solution though :) +1

Answer (score 1):

`(?:\s+)` can be reduced to `\s+`. `/^(?!notstart).*".*"/` seems sufficient though. Ensure `notstart` is not at the beginning, then validate that there are at least two quotes elsewhere in the string.

```js
[
  'notstart testing "testing"', // false
  'start testing "testing"',    // true
  'anything testing testing'    // false
].forEach(e => console.log(/^(?!notstart).*".*"/.test(e)));
```

If you want to capture the item in quotes:

```js
[
  'notstart testing "testing"', // null
  'start testing "testing"',    // "testing"
  'anything testing testing'    // null
].forEach(e => console.log(e.match(/^(?!notstart).*"([^"]*)"/)));
```

If you want spaces around the quoted word, you can use:

```js
const pattern = /^(?!notstart).*(?:\s|^)"([^"]*)"(?:\s|$)/;
[
  'notstart testing "testing"', // null
  'start testing "testing"',    // "testing"
  'anything testing testing',   // null
  'anything testing"testing"',  // null
  '"foo"'                       // foo
].forEach(e => console.log(e.match(pattern)));
```

If you want to capture all quoted strings, this should avoid backtracking:

```js
[
  'notstart testing "testing"', // null
  'start testing "testing"',    // "testing"
  'start testing "foo" "bar"',  // "foo" "bar"
].forEach(e => {
  let m;
  
  if (!e.startsWith("notstart") && 
      (m = [...e.matchAll(/"([^"]*)"/g)]).length) {
    console.log(m);
  }
  else {
    console.log(null);
  }
});
```

Comment: please check with regexp /(?<!^notstart.*)"[^"]*"$/
its working for single double quote value present in string not for multiple double quote value like

start testing "testing" "check" => "testing" "check"

Comment: Updated. How does it look now? BTW, when asking a question, it's a good idea to clearly state all of your requirements up front to avoid confusion.

Comment: Perhaps you could also make `(.*?)` a negated character class `([^"]*)` +1

Comment: Would the behavior be any different? The two seem equivalent.

Comment: Not sure how it will work internally in the engine, but I think in general it prevents backtracking.

Comment: Yes, a negated character class would be faster than `.*` or `.*?` as there is no backtracking.

Comment: Yeah, I think the engine may need to look 1 character ahead with my version. I'll update.